# Logo does not show up on every page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I've set a logo for my rails application and it shows up on every static page. But if I sign in, the newly created link `users/1` does not display it anymore,the same with `users/index`.
Here's my `_header.html.erb`:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="containers">
      <a href='/'><img src="image1.png"  alt='image'></a>
   <%= link_to "Cherry Pie", root_path, id: "logo" %>
  </div>
</header>
```

The logo is now located in `assets/images` folder. I tried to move it into `public` folder but nothing changed. How can I make it show the same way on every page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image in the public folder you can use image_tag for view on every page ;

```
<%= image_tag "/../image1.png" %>
```

More about image_tag [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag).

Comment: I've changed the link to `<img src="/../image1.png" alt='image'>` and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: use  `image_path`